# I've seen two definitions of subspace; one involving vector spaces and one requiring linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The first definition of subspace I was exposed to is: A subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is any collection S of vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that:

1. The zero vector 0 is in S
2. If u and v are in S, then u + v is in S
3. If u is in S and c is a scalar, then cu is in S

And you can combine 2 and 3 into one requirement, which is that S be closed under linear combinations.

The second definition of subspace I saw, much later on, was: A subset W of a vector space V is called a subspace of V if W is itself a vector space with the same scalars, addition, and scalar multiplication as V.

I'm a bit confused on the difference between these two definitions. How do I reconcile one with the other? Is there any meaningful difference between the two? As far as I know, vector spaces are also required to be closed under linear combinations, so isn't the second definition saying the same exact thing as the first definition?

One idea I have is that the second definition is a more general form of the first definition, since the first definition is talking about $\mathbb{R^n}$ (and $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a vector space), while the second definition is talking about all vector spaces (including $\mathbb{R^n}$ and more). Is this the correct interpretation? And are there any other differences between the two definitions that I'm missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The definitions are equivalent

Comment: In the first definition, you can replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an arbitrary vector space as well.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions are equivalent.

A subspace V of a vector space W is a subset of W that is itself a vector space.

It turns out that all we have to do is show the following:

- 0 is in V
- V is closed under addition
- V is closed under scalar multiplication

Since we know that V is a subset of W then we know that all the other properties of a vector space are satisfied.  For example, we know that if a and b are in V then a+b = b+a.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not 2 definitions, but a definition and a criterion. The criterion being your first "definition".

So, a subset $W$ of the $K$-vector space $V$ is a subspace if the structure it inherits from $V$ makes it a vector space. That's the **definition**, but it's unpractical to check.

If you are to prove that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, it is more convenient to check the **criterion**:

- $0_V \in W$
- $\forall u,v \in W,\, \forall \lambda \in K, \, u + \lambda v \in W$